# Horizontal and vertical alignment of a picture in a table

Tags: tables, graphics, horizontal-alignment

I want to align a picture in a cell of a table.
Following works as I want for the text in the top left cell and the picture is already vertically aligned, but not horizontally:

```
\begin{tabular}{m{0.04\textwidth}|m{0.325\textwidth}|m{0.6\textwidth}}
 \toprule
  \centering{a} & b & \includegraphics[draft]{test}\\ \midrule
  d             & e & f\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

However placing `\includegraphics{test}` into a `\centering{}` results in following  error message:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\midrule ->\noalign 
                {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global \@...
l.338 ...test}}\\ \midrule
? 
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.339   d &
            e & f\
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\centering` does not take an argument, making `\centering{a}` be no different from `\centering a`. Also, `\centering` used in your instance has no effect within a `tabular`. Horizontal `\centering` is obtained using

```
\hfill\includegraphics[..]{...}\hfill\null
```

Alternatively, if you want the entire column to use `\centering`, you can use

```
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{..}
```

as the column type (the above support is also provided by [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array)).

Comment: Thank you. I've just found a [tex-faq](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=tabcellalign) discussing the problem  of “misplaced \noalign” complaints when using `\centering`, `\raggedright`, `\raggedleft` in a table.