# Vertically align cell table in figure

Tags: tables, floats, vertical-alignment

I have the following figure:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \includegraphics{combo} & \includegraphics{combomenu}
    \end{tabular}
\caption{A combo box with and without showing the menu.}
\label{fig:combos}
\end{figure}
```

which produces:

[image]

The left image is significantly shorther than the right image. How do I vertically align the left image to the top of the cell?

I would already overheat Google with my searches on how to do it, if it would be possible. Nothing I do just seems to have any effect on it:

- `\includegraphics{combo}\hfill` does nothing
- `\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|c|}` does nothing, apart from setting the columnt width
- `\raisebox{4.5\height}{\includegraphics{combo}}` indeed moves the image up and down, but I just cannot seem to get the parameter right. Something between 5.5 and 6 it seems. But that's really not what I want, if I decide to change the second image, I would have to go through the painstaking alignment process again.
- Using minipages aligns the image to the top, but also adds more space to the right from both images and maybe pushes the images too far up, so that the vertical lines begin slightly off:

[image]

I specified the images' width in pixels, they are both 82 pixels wide.

Comment: AFAIK there are several ways you could tackle that, see for example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51564 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67052 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6355

Comment: @CountZero pls see edit

Comment: Without any packages, `\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[...]{...}` should do.

Comment: @egreg that commang pushes the image even more downwards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % just to provide mock figures
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=.5cm]{x}} &
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=3cm]{x}} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without any package,

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=.5cm]{x}} &
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=3cm]{x}} \\
\end{tabular}
```

would do the same.

Comment: @JakubZaverka: If you load `adjustbox` (v0.8 or later) with the `export` option you can use the `valign` key directly with `\includegraphics`, after the size keys.

Comment: This works, but a note about something I needed some time to discover: you have to apply `adjustbox` to all cells in a row even if you only want to change the vertical alignment of one of them.

Answer (score 3):

Another minipage solution with a few more optional arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe} %< -- For dummy images

\begin{document}%
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \begin{minipage}[b][6cm][t]{2cm} %[minipage place][height][content align]{width}
        \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{example-image-a}%
        \end{minipage}
            & \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=6cm]{example-image-b}
    \end{tabular}
\caption{A combo box with and without showing the menu.}
\label{fig:combos}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would put both `\includegraphics` commands inside minipages as follows:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{<width-of-image>}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}\par
    \includegraphics{combo}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}[t]{<width-of-image>}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}\par
    \includegraphics{combomenu}
\end{minipage}
```

Though I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Variation of egreg answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% tested with version 1.0

\begin{document}%
    \begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm,valign=t]{example-image-a}%
    &   \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=6cm,valign=t]{example-image-b}
    \end{tabular}
\caption{A combo box with and without showing the menu.}
\label{fig:combos}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

gives the same result as shown in *egreg* answer